# is it possible to edit the worker node manifest manually?

Tags: kubernetes

there are 16 cores on the worker node machine, and 8 are listed in the node manifest. It's unclear how this happened, but that's not the point. How safe is it to edit manifest nodes manually for a larger number of cores and RAM?

Comment: Refer this [document](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/ContEng/Tasks/contengmodifyingnodepool.htm) may be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

editing yml did not help, after restarting the VM everything took off well